# Trying to set a span element equal to a variable value in a JS Rock, Paper, Scissors Game

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm writing a program to play rock, paper, scissors. As I was coding, everything was going fine until I added the:

```
userScore_span.InnerHTML = userScore;
```

line. When testing out the win function, I added a console.log('you win'); and it worked fine, but as soon as I added the line from above I got an error when I pressed any one of the three buttons.

I'm trying to relay the result from userScore to userScore_span given that userScore increases after a game is won

```
userScore++;
userScore_span.innerHTML = userScore;
```

However, when I press any of the buttons I get an error of:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null
at lose (app.js:34)
at game (app.js:58)
```

I am not sure what the chrome Dev tools means by this. How can this be fixed?

```js
let userScore = 0;
let computerScore = 0;
const userScore_span = document.getElementById("user-score");
const computerScore_span = document.getElementById("computer-score");
const scoreBoard_div = document.querySelector(".score-board");
const result_p = document.querySelector(".result > p");
const rock_div = document.getElementById('r');
const paper_div = document.getElementById('p');
const scissors_div = document.getElementById('s');

function getComputerChoice() {
  const choices = ['r', 'p', 's'];
  const randomNumber = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 3));
  return choices[randomNumber];
}

function convertToWord(letter) {
  if (letter === "r") return "Rock";
  if (letter === "p") return "Paper";
  return "Scissors";
}

function win(userChoice, computerChoice) {
  userScore++;
  userScore_span.innerHTML = userScore;
  computerScore_span.innerHTML = computerScore;
  const smallUserWord = "user".fontsize(3).sub();
  const smallCompWord = "comp".fontsize(3).sub();
  result_p.innerHTML = `${convertToWord(userChoice)}${smallUserWord} beats ${convertToWord(computerChoice)}${smallCompWord}. You win!`;
}

function lose(userChoice, computerChoice) {
  computerScore++;
  userScore_span.innerHTML = userScore;
  computerScore_span.innerHTML = computerScore;
  const smallUserWord = "user".fontsize(3).sub();
  const smallCompWord = "comp".fontsize(3).sub();
  result_p.innerHTML = `${convertToWord(userChoice)}${smallUserWord} loses to ${convertToWord(computerChoice)}${smallCompWord}. You lost!`;
}

function draw(userChoice, computerChoice) {
  const smallUserWord = "user".fontsize(3).sub();
  const smallCompWord = "comp".fontsize(3).sub();
  result_p.innerHTML = `${convertToWord(userChoice)}${smallUserWord} equals ${convertToWord(computerChoice)}${smallCompWord}. It's a draw`;
}

function game(userChoice) {
  const computerChoice = getComputerChoice();
  switch (userChoice + computerChoice) {
    case "rs":
    case "pr":
    case "sp":
      win(userChoice, computerChoice);
      break;
    case 'rp':
    case 'ps':
    case 'sr':
      lose(userChoice, computerChoice);
      break;
    case 'rr':
    case 'pp':
    case 'ss':
      draw(userChoice, computerChoice);
      break;
  }
}

function main() {
  rock_div.addEventListener('click', function() {
    game('r');
  })
  paper_div.addEventListener('click', function() {
    game('p');
  })
  scissors_div.addEventListener('click', function() {
    game('s');
  })
};

main();
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #24272E;
  font-family: avenir;
}

header {
  background: white;
  padding: 20px;
}


/*header each one*/

header>h1 {
  color: #24272E;
  text-align: center;
}

.score-board {
  border: 3px solid white;
  border-radius: 4px;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  /*20px (top/bottom) & center (left/right) */
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 46px;
  position: relative;
}

.badge {
  background: #E2584D;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 2px 10px;
}

#user-label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  left: -25px;
}

#computer-label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  right: -30px;
}

.result {
  font-size: 40px;
  color: white;
}

.result>p {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.choices {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.choice {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 4px solid white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0 20px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.choice:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: darkblue;
}

img {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

#action-message {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Rock Paper Scissors</title>
  <meta name="description" content="DESCRIPTION">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <h1>Rock Paper Scissors</h1>
  </header>
  <div class="score-board">
    <div id="user-label" class="badge">user</div>
    <div id="computer-label" class="badge">comp</div>
    <span idea="user-score">0</span>:<span idea="computer-score">0</span>
  </div>

  <div class="result">
    <p>Paper cover rock. You win!</p>
  </div>

  <div class="choices">
    <div class="choice" id="r">
      <img src="images/rock.png" alt="rock">
    </div>
    <div class="choice" id="p">
      <img src="images/paper.png" alt="paper">
    </div>
    <div class="choice" id="s">
      <img src="images/scissors.png" alt="scissors">
    </div>
  </div>

  <p id="action-message">Make your move</p>






</body>
<script src="app.js"></script>

</html>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/sub so, don't. Use HTML tags, CSS, `createElement` is you will.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Beside your typo `idea=` / `id=` ...
you could drastically **minify your game logic** and code by **using indexes** integers.

### Game of integers

- Use `data-*` attribute for user buttons. The attributes should hold numerical values `0, 1, 2`. On click, the value will represents the player choice.
- The AI should play numbers too: `const AI = ~~(Math.random() * 3) // 0, 1, 2`

Now that you know AI and Player both **use integers** (instead of strange letters combinations), you can store the *Move names* into an array  `const moves = ["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"];` (where `0` is *Rock*... etc)

### Rock Paper Scissors Logic

The game has **three** possible *round resolutions*, **PL wins, AI wins, Draw**.
Let's convert those *"human"* values to integers, in the same order:

- `0` = PL win
- `1` = AI win
- `2` = Draw

Here's how to calculate those:

#### Draw

To calculate a Draw is the simplest. It's when both `AI` and `PL` integers are equal. **Let's return `2`**

```
result = PL === AI ? 2
```

#### Player wins

To calculate Player win, simply **increment AI choice by 1 and do a modulo 3**. If the result of this operation is equal to player's choice, than Player must have won! **Let's return `0`**

#### AI wins

Else, since our game has only 3 possible states, it's not a draw, and it's not a player win, than must be AI win! **And let's return `1`**

```
const result = PL===AI ? 2 : (AI+1)%3 === PL? 0 : 1; // Possible results: 0, 1, 2
```

The cool thing in having a game result index based too is that now you can use also an array of messages like `messages = ["You won!", "AI won", "it's a draw!", ]` and **get the desired message by the result index!**. And bonus! You can also increment the `score` array values, `0` being the player's index and `1` being AIs!

```js
const moves = ["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"],
  messages  = ["You won!", "AI won", "It's a draw!"], // [PL, AI, draw]
  score     = [0, 0, 0],                              // [PL, AI, draw]
  EL = sel => document.querySelector(sel),
  EL_result  = EL("#result"),
  EL_PLScore = EL("#PLScore"),
  EL_AIScore = EL("#AIScore");

function game() {
  const PL = +this.dataset.playermove;  // Get dataset value as integer
  const AI = ~~(Math.random() * 3);     // All you need: 0, 1, 2
  const result = PL === AI ? 2 : (AI + 1) % 3 === PL ? 0 : 1; // 0=PLwins 1=AIwins 2=draw 

  score[result]++; // Increment PL or AI's score (Increments number of draws too ;) )
  EL_result.innerHTML = `You: ${moves[PL]}<br>AI: ${moves[AI]}<br>${messages[result]}`;
  EL_PLScore.textContent = score[0];
  EL_AIScore.textContent = score[1];
}

// EVENTS:
document.querySelectorAll("[data-playermove]")
  .forEach(el => el.addEventListener("click", game));
```

```html
<button data-playermove="0">ROCK</button>
<button data-playermove="1">PAPER</button>
<button data-playermove="2">SCISSORS</button>

<br>

YOU | <span id="PLScore">0</span>:<span id="AIScore">0</span> | AI

<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: `+String` and `~~(float)` certainly do work for converting to and "flooring" a number, respectively, but to aid readability I would advise using `Number(String)` and `Math.floor(float)` for these cases.

Comment: Also, you didn't explain your intention, you just put your implementation into words. If you want people to understand the reason behind your implementation, you need to explain your thought process, i.e. it's not clear to everyone why `(AI + 1) % 3 === PL` means that AI has won.

Comment: @OskarGrosser thank you for pointing that out! (*To the reader:*) A more readable  expansion of the above's code `(AI + 1) % 3 === PL` can be found On [this example of Rock Paper 
 Scissors logic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65222507/rock-paper-scissors-coding-challenege). And yes `~~` is used instead of `Math.floor()`. The unary prefix `+` is pretty common in JS programming to convert a String to Number. Clearly I could have used more explicitly `Number(str)`

Answer (score 0):

**Typo: `idea` <> `id`**

Change this:

```
<span idea="user-score">0</span>:<span idea="computer-score">0</span>
```

to

```
<span id="user-score">0</span>:<span id="computer-score">0</span>
```

```js
let userScore = 0;
let computerScore = 0;
const userScore_span = document.getElementById("user-score");
const computerScore_span = document.getElementById("computer-score");
const scoreBoard_div = document.querySelector(".score-board");
const result_p = document.querySelector(".result > p");
const rock_div = document.getElementById('r');
const paper_div = document.getElementById('p');
const scissors_div = document.getElementById('s');

function getComputerChoice() {
  const choices = ['r', 'p', 's'];
  const randomNumber = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 3));
  return choices[randomNumber];
}

function convertToWord(letter) {
  if (letter === "r") return "Rock";
  if (letter === "p") return "Paper";
  return "Scissors";
}

function win(userChoice, computerChoice) {
  userScore++;
  userScore_span.innerHTML = userScore;
  computerScore_span.innerHTML = computerScore;
  const smallUserWord = "user".fontsize(3).sub();
  const smallCompWord = "comp".fontsize(3).sub();
  result_p.innerHTML = `${convertToWord(userChoice)}${smallUserWord} beats ${convertToWord(computerChoice)}${smallCompWord}. You win!`;
}

function lose(userChoice, computerChoice) {
  computerScore++;
  userScore_span.innerHTML = userScore;
  computerScore_span.innerHTML = computerScore;
  const smallUserWord = "user".fontsize(3).sub();
  const smallCompWord = "comp".fontsize(3).sub();
  result_p.innerHTML = `${convertToWord(userChoice)}${smallUserWord} loses to ${convertToWord(computerChoice)}${smallCompWord}. You lost!`;
}

function draw(userChoice, computerChoice) {
  const smallUserWord = "user".fontsize(3).sub();
  const smallCompWord = "comp".fontsize(3).sub();
  result_p.innerHTML = `${convertToWord(userChoice)}${smallUserWord} equals ${convertToWord(computerChoice)}${smallCompWord}. It's a draw`;
}

function game(userChoice) {
  const computerChoice = getComputerChoice();
  switch (userChoice + computerChoice) {
    case "rs":
    case "pr":
    case "sp":
      win(userChoice, computerChoice);
      break;
    case 'rp':
    case 'ps':
    case 'sr':
      lose(userChoice, computerChoice);
      break;
    case 'rr':
    case 'pp':
    case 'ss':
      draw(userChoice, computerChoice);
      break;
  }
}

function main() {
  rock_div.addEventListener('click', function() {
    game('r');
  })
  paper_div.addEventListener('click', function() {
    game('p');
  })
  scissors_div.addEventListener('click', function() {
    game('s');
  })
};

main();
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #24272E;
  font-family: avenir;
}

header {
  background: white;
  padding: 20px;
}


/*header each one*/

header>h1 {
  color: #24272E;
  text-align: center;
}

.score-board {
  border: 3px solid white;
  border-radius: 4px;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  /*20px (top/bottom) & center (left/right) */
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 46px;
  position: relative;
}

.badge {
  background: #E2584D;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 2px 10px;
}

#user-label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  left: -25px;
}

#computer-label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  right: -30px;
}

.result {
  font-size: 40px;
  color: white;
}

.result>p {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.choices {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.choice {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 4px solid white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0 20px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.choice:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: darkblue;
}

img {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

#action-message {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Rock Paper Scissors</title>
  <meta name="description" content="DESCRIPTION">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <h1>Rock Paper Scissors</h1>
  </header>
  <div class="score-board">
    <div id="user-label" class="badge">user</div>
    <div id="computer-label" class="badge">comp</div>
    <span id="user-score">0</span>:<span id="computer-score">0</span>
  </div>

  <div class="result">
    <p>Paper cover rock. You win!</p>
  </div>

  <div class="choices">
    <div class="choice" id="r">
      <img src="images/rock.png" alt="rock">
    </div>
    <div class="choice" id="p">
      <img src="images/paper.png" alt="paper">
    </div>
    <div class="choice" id="s">
      <img src="images/scissors.png" alt="scissors">
    </div>
  </div>

  <p id="action-message">Make your move</p>






</body>
<script src="app.js"></script>

</html>
```