# How do I make a function that reset the game on click

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on a rock paper scissor game. I'm very new to javascript and only know the basics. The code is a little sloppy. What I want is to be able to continue playing the game after a choice is selected. For example, right now if I click rock, the CPU will randomize a result, but then if I click on paper, the result will stay on the screen and the new result will overlap the old one.

I was thinking of adding another condition to the if statements. Also, I was thinking of adding another function to the return of the if statement that might reset it.

**html**

```
<div class="main-container">
  <div class="score">
    <p>You:0</p>
    <p>Computer:0</p>
  </div>

  <div class="user-choice">
    <img id="rock" class="choice" src="icons/rock.png">
    <img id="paper" class="choice" src="icons/paper.png">
    <img id="scissors" class="choice" src="icons/scissors.png">
  </div>
  <div class="cpu-result">
    <img class="cpu-rock" src="icons/rock.png">
    <img class="cpu-paper" src="icons/paper.png">
    <img class="cpu-scissors" src="icons/scissors.png">
  </div>
</div>
```

**js**

```
const userChoice = document.querySelectorAll('.choice')
const cpuScissors = document.querySelector('.cpu-scissors')
const cpuPaper = document.querySelector('.cpu-paper')
const cpuRock = document.querySelector('.cpu-rock')


function cpuChoice() {
  const rand = Math.random()
  if (rand < .34) {
    cpuPaper.style.display = 'inline-block'
  } else if (rand >= .67) {
    cpuRock.style.display = 'inline-block'
  } else {
    cpuScissors.style.display = 'inline-block'
  }
}

userChoice.forEach(userChoice =>
userChoice.addEventListener('click', cpuChoice))
```

**css**

```
.cpu-scissors {
  display: none;
}

.cpu-paper {
  display: none;
}

.cpu-rock {
  display: none;
}

.cpu-result img {
  position: absolute;
  height: 11rem;
}
```

Comment: is there a css snippet that you are missing?

Comment: I added in the css that i thought was related to what im trying to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you need to remove `position: absolute;` for `img` which was causing the overlapping.

Secondly, each time you call `cpuChoice()`, you need to hide the previous element before showing the current element.

```js
const userChoice = document.querySelectorAll('.choice')
const cpuScissors = document.querySelector('.cpu-scissors')
const cpuPaper = document.querySelector('.cpu-paper')
const cpuRock = document.querySelector('.cpu-rock')
let currentItem;

function cpuChoice() {
  const rand = Math.random();
  if (currentItem) {
    currentItem.style.display = 'none';
  }
  if (rand < .34) {
    cpuPaper.style.display = 'inline-block';
    currentItem = cpuPaper;
  } else if (rand >= .67) {
    cpuRock.style.display = 'inline-block';
    currentItem = cpuRock;
  } else {
    cpuScissors.style.display = 'inline-block';
    currentItem = cpuScissors;
  }
}

userChoice.forEach(userChoice =>
  userChoice.addEventListener('click', cpuChoice));
```

```css
.cpu-scissors {
  display: none;
}

.cpu-paper {
  display: none;
}

.cpu-rock {
  display: none;
}

.cpu-result img {
  height: 5rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
  <div class="score">
    <p>You:0</p>
    <p>Computer:0</p>
  </div>

  <div class="user-choice">
    <img id="rock" class="choice" src="icons/rock.png">
    <img id="paper" class="choice" src="icons/paper.png">
    <img id="scissors" class="choice" src="icons/scissors.png">
  </div>
  <div class="cpu-result">
    <img class="cpu-rock" src="icons/rock.png">
    <img class="cpu-paper" src="icons/paper.png">
    <img class="cpu-scissors" src="icons/scissors.png">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need all those IDs and Classes.
**Use Indexes!**

Using indexes you can also retrieve the winner
See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53983473/383904

```js
const moves  = ["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"],
  messages   = ["You won!", "AI won", "It's a draw!"], // [PL, AI, draw]
  score      = [0, 0, 0],                              // [PL, AI, draw]
  ELS        = sel => document.querySelectorAll(sel),
  EL_result  = ELS("#result")[0],
  EL_PLScore = ELS("#PLScore")[0],
  EL_AIScore = ELS("#AIScore")[0],
  ELS_ai     = ELS(".ai");

function game() {
  const PL = +this.dataset.user;        // Get played index as integer
  const AI = ~~(Math.random() * 3);     // All you need: 0, 1, 2
  const result = PL === AI ? 2 : (AI + 1) % 3 === PL ? 0 : 1; // 0=PLwins 1=AIwins 2=draw 

  score[result]++; // Increment PL or AI's score (Increments number of draws too ;) )
  EL_result.innerHTML = `You: ${moves[PL]}, AI: ${moves[AI]}, ${messages[result]}`;
  EL_PLScore.textContent = score[0];
  EL_AIScore.textContent = score[1];
  
  ELS_ai.forEach(el => el.classList.remove('inline-block')); // Hide all
  ELS_ai[AI].classList.add('inline-block');                  // Show one
}

// EVENTS:
document.querySelectorAll("[data-user]").forEach(el => el.addEventListener("click", game));
```

```css
.ai {
  display: none;
}

.ai.inline-block {
  display: inline-block
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
  <div class="score">
    <span>You: <span id="PLScore">0</span></span>
    <span>Computer: <span id="AIScore">0</span></span>
  </div>

  <div class="user-choice">
    <img data-user="0" src="//placehold.it/50x50/888?text=ROCK">
    <img data-user="1" src="//placehold.it/50x50/eee?text=PAPER">
    <img data-user="2" src="//placehold.it/50x50/0bf?text=SCISSORS">
  </div>
  <div class="cpu-result">
    <img class="ai" src="//placehold.it/50x50/888?text=ROCK">
    <img class="ai" src="//placehold.it/50x50/eee?text=PAPER">
    <img class="ai" src="//placehold.it/50x50/0bf?text=SCISSORS">
  </div>
  
  <div id="result"></div>

</div>
```