# My Rock, Pape, Scissors JQuery Code is Illogical

Tags: jquery, logic

I am creating a Jquery version of RPS. I challenge I am doing to build on my Front End Development skills. Everything was going well up until the Javascript had to be integrated. Specifically, the code that determines who the winner is and which text to display. Ill show all the code so you can all have an idea of whats going on.

```js
/*-----OPEN RULES MENU-----*/

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#rules-btn").click(function() {
    $("#rules-overlay").css("display", "flex");
  })
})

/*-----CLOSE RULES MENU-----*/

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#close").click(function() {
    $("#rules-overlay").css("display", "none");
  })
})

/*-----USERS CHOICE-----*/

var rock = "<div id='rock' class='container-outside'><div class='container-inside'><img id='rock-icon' src='images/icon-rock.svg' alt='rock_icon'></div></div>";

var paper = "<div id='paper' class='container-outside'><div class='container-inside'><img id='paper-icon' src='images/icon-paper.svg' alt='paper_icon'></div></div>";

var scissors = "<div id='scissors' class='container-outside'><div class='container-inside'><img id='scissors-icon' src='images/icon-scissors.svg' alt='scissors_icon'></div></div>";

var houseChoice = function() {
  var random = Math.random();
  if (random < 0.333) {
    return rock;
  } else if (random < 0.67777) {
    return paper;
  } else {
    return scissors;
  }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#paper").click(function() {
    $("#game").hide();
    $("#game-in-progress").show();
    $("#user-choice").html(paper);
    $("#house-choice").html(houseChoice());
    if (houseChoice() === rock) {
      $("#who-won").text("You Win");
    } else if (houseChoice() === scissors) {
      $("#who-won").text("You Lose");
    } else if (houseChoice() === paper) {
      $("#who-won").text("You Tied");
    }
  })
})
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#rock").click(function() {
    $("#game").hide();
    $("#game-in-progress").show();
    $("#user-choice").html(rock);
    $("#house-choice").html(houseChoice());
    if (houseChoice() === rock) {
      $("#who-won").text("You Tied");
    } else if (houseChoice() === scissors) {
      $("#who-won").text("You Win");
    } else if (houseChoice() === paper) {
      $("#who-won").text("You Lose");
    }
  })
})
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#scissors").click(function() {
    $("#game").hide();
    $("#game-in-progress").show();
    $("#user-choice").html(scissors);
    $("#house-choice").html(houseChoice());
    if (houseChoice() === rock) {
      $("#who-won").text("You Lose");
    } else if (houseChoice() === scissors) {
      $("#who-won").text("You Tied");
    } else if (houseChoice() === paper) {
      $("#who-won").text("You Win");
    }
  })
})

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#play-again").click(function() {
    if ($("#who-won").text() === "You Win") {

    }
  })
})
```

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background-image: radial-gradient(hsl(214, 47%, 23%), hsl(237, 49%, 15%));
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  overflow: hidden;
}

h3 {
  line-height: 1;
}

/*-----SCORE-----*/

#header-box {
  width: 60%;
  height: 125px;
  border: 2px solid hsl(217, 16%, 45%);
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 30px 0px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

#title {
  font-family: 'Barlow Semi Condensed', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: white;
  margin: 0px 20px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 26px;
}

#score-tracker {
  height: 100px;
  width: 120px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  background: white;
  margin: 0px 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

#score-title {
  color: hsl(229, 64%, 46%);
  font-family: 'Barlow Semi Condensed', sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  margin: 0px;
}

#score {
  font-family: 'Barlow Semi Condensed', sans-serif;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: hsl(229, 25%, 31%);
  margin: 0px;
}


/*-----GAMEBOARD-----*/

#game {
  height: 350px;
  width: 350px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-image: url("images/bg-triangle.svg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 50% 60%;
  background-size: 250px;
}

#game-top,
#game-btm {
  height: 175px;
  width: 350px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

#game-top {
  justify-content: space-between;
}

#game-btm {
  justify-content: center;
}

#paper {
  background-image: linear-gradient(hsl(230, 89%, 62%), hsl(230, 89%, 65%));
}

#scissors {
  background-image: linear-gradient(hsl(39, 89%, 49%), hsl(40, 84%, 53%));
}

#rock {
  background-image: linear-gradient(hsl(349, 71%, 52%), hsl(349, 70%, 56%));
}

#rock-icon,
#paper-icon,
#scissors-icon {
  transition: transform .3s;
}

#rock:hover #rock-icon,
#scissors:hover #scissors-icon,
#paper:hover #paper-icon {
  transform: rotate(30deg);
}


/*-----GAME IN PROGRESS-----*/

#game-in-progress {
  height: 300px;
  display: none;
}

#selections {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 300px;
  align-items: center;
}

#user-selection,
#house-selection {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 300px;
  width: 250px;
  margin: 0px 20px;
  transition: transform .3s;
}

#user-choice,
#house-choice {
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
}

#results {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 0px 25px;
}

#who-won {
  font-family: 'Barlow Semi Condensed', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 40px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin: 5px 0px;
}

#play-again {
  height: 40px;
  width: 150px;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-family: 'Barlow Semi Condensed', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 11px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border: none;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  color: hsl(229, 64%, 46%);
  cursor: pointer;
}


/*-----RULES-----*/

#rules {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 30px 0px;
  align-self: flex-end;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

#rules-btn {
  margin: 0px 50px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 35px;
  background: inherit;
  border: 1px solid hsl(217, 16%, 45%);
  border-radius: 7px;
  font-family: 'Barlow Semi Condensed', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: white;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#rules-overlay {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  z-index: 2;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}

#rules-box {
  height: 350px;
  width: 300px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: white;
}

#rules-nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  width: 80%;
  padding: 0px 10%;
}

#rules-title {
  font-family: 'Barlow Semi Condensed', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: hsl(229, 25%, 31%);
  font-size: 24px;
}

#close {
  color: hsl(229, 25%, 31%);
  cursor: pointer;
}

#rules-img {
  width: 250px;
  display: block;
  margin: 25px auto;
}


/*CLASSES*/

.container-outside {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 150px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  box-shadow: inset 0px -5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.container-inside {
  height: 115px;
  width: 115px;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 100px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 5px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}

.selection-title {
  font-family: 'Barlow Semi Condensed', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.bg-circle {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -50px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="rules-overlay">
  <div id="rules-box">
    <div id="rules-nav">
      <h3 id="rules-title">Rules</h3>
      <i id="close" class="fas fa-times fa-lg"></i>
    </div>
    <img id="rules-img" src="images/image-rules.svg" alt="rules">
  </div>
</div>
<header id="header-box">
  <div>
    <h3 id="title">Rock<br>Paper<br>Scissors</h3>
  </div>
  <div id="score-tracker">
    <h5 id="score-title">Score</h5>
    <h2 id="score">00</h2>
  </div>
</header>

<!--GAME BOARD-->
<div id="game">
  <div id="game-top">
    <div id="paper" class="container-outside">
      <div class="container-inside">
        <img id="paper-icon" src="images/icon-paper.svg" alt="paper_icon">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="scissors" class="container-outside">
      <div class="container-inside">
        <img id="scissors-icon" src="images/icon-scissors.svg" alt="scissors_icon">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="game-btm">
    <div id="rock" class="container-outside">
      <div class="container-inside">
        <img id="rock-icon" src="images/icon-rock.svg" alt="rock_icon">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!--GAME IN PROGRESS-->
<div id="game-in-progress">
  <div id="selections">
    <div id="user-selection">
      <h3 class="selection-title">You Picked</h3>
      <div id="user-choice">
        <div class="bg-circle"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="results">
      <h1 id="who-won"></h1>
      <button id="play-again">Play Again</button>
    </div>
    <div id="house-selection">
      <h3 class="selection-title">The House Picked</h3>
      <div id="house-choice">
        <div class="bg-circle"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!--RULES-->
<div id="rules">
  <button id="rules-btn">Rules</button>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

The issue begins with the logic of the rock, paper scissor game. Can someone please examine this javascript and tell me what im doing wrong. Thanks.

Comment: See this interesting Answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/53983473/383904 or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57742568/383904) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58924963/383904)

Comment: ID should be unique on a page. In JS you're reinserting elements which ID already exist in DOM