# Rock Paper Scissors coding challenege

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a Rock Paper Scissors coding challenge for myself, and I got a simple version with a text box, so no I'm trying to make it with buttons, I have made it very far through, I'm just on the last step.

So what I want to do is take the info from the rock(), paper(), and scissors() functions and go further

This is what I have so far

```
var playerInput = "blank"
    
function rock(playerInput) {
    this.playerInput = playerInput; 
    playerInput = "rock";
}

function paper(playerInput) {
    this.playerInput = playerInput; 
    playerInput = "paper";
}

function scissors() {
    this.playerInput = playerInput; 
    playerInput = "scissors";
}
```

and what I want to do from there is take it into another function where I have already created the game itself.

I've tried

```
var rock = rock();
console.log(rock.playerInput);
```

and it didn't work please help.

Comment: `this` works with objects only, and a function must return a value in order to use that outside of the function. If run the code in sloppy mode, all your functions are just assigning the string to `playerInput`, which is a global variable. That means, that `this.playerInput === playerInput`.

Comment: I like to help students. If you want, we can have a video call over google meet. Please let me know if you need.

Comment: I just want to add, it did give me an error, not sure if this is related. The error was ``` <a class='gotoLine' href='#81:13'>81:13</a> Uncaught TypeError: rock is not a function"```

Comment: Super useful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53983473/383904

Comment: I've looked at it, and I don't know what much of it means, it has a lot of things I don't really understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here's a super useful example][1] on how to tackle the **Rock, Paper, Scissors game logic** using buttons.

Besides that, **you don't need multiple functions**, programming is not about copy/pasting code around a file, but to determine the characteristics we can reuse.

Use `data-*` attributes to store the figure index:

```js
function play() {
  const player = Number(this.dataset.player); // Get 0, 1, 2 from button data-player
  const computer = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3); // Generate random 0, 1, 2 integer
  console.log(`PLAYER: ${player} COMPUTER:${computer}`);

  // Game logic goes here
}

const buttons = document.querySelectorAll("[data-player]");

buttons.forEach(function(el) {
  el.addEventListener("click", play);
});
```

```html
<button data-player="0" type="button">ROCK</button>
<button data-player="1" type="button">PAPER</button>
<button data-player="2" type="button">SCISSORS</button>
```

Given the above, you got pretty much all the needed data.

- Both player and computer values are an integer `0` (rock), `1` (paper), `2` (scissors)

## Example of Rock Paper Scissors game with result

```js
const fig = ["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"];
const msg = ["You won!", "You lost :(", "It's a draw"];

function play() {
  const player = Number(this.dataset.player); // Get 0, 1, 2 from button data-player
  const computer = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3); // Generate random 0, 1, 2 integer

  // Game logic goes here
  // See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53983473/383904
  let result;
  if (player === computer) {
    result = 2; // Draw
  } else if ((computer + 1) % 3 === player) {
    result = 0; // Player wins
  } else {
    result = 1; // Computer wins
  }

  console.log(`PLAYER:${fig[player]} COMPUTER:${fig[computer]} ${msg[result]}`);
}

const buttons = document.querySelectorAll("[data-player]");

buttons.forEach(function(el) {
  el.addEventListener("click", play);
});
```

```html
<button data-player="0" type="button">ROCK</button>
<button data-player="1" type="button">PAPER</button>
<button data-player="2" type="button">SCISSORS</button>
```

Another resource that explains the logic is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70815049/383904)
[1]: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53983473/383904

Comment: what does ```Number(this.dataset.player);```
 do, and also what do the $ signs mean

Comment: I think i understand actually, the This.dataset means you can use data-player = in the HTML but i dont know what the $ signs mean

Comment: This worked really well, and I know how to take this further, I just want to know what it all does

Comment: @ZainWilson-WCHStudent https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals I used template literals instead of `+` to concatenate strings with variables.

Comment: `this` is the clicked button, `this.dataset` is a way to read the button's data-* atribute, `this.dataset.player` is the value of the `data-player="XY"` attribute. `Number` is...   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number used to convert the string to Number. Refer to the docs for whatever you don't understand - or ask

Comment: One more question, what does the el do in 
```forEach (el => { el.addEventListener("click", play);});```

Comment: @ZainWilson-WCHStudent I edited the answer... changed the Arrow function to be a regular function. Hope you'll find it easier to understand. Please read: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach `el` is the currently iterating button (since we have three of them!) - Inside the forEach loop you assign a click to that specific button.

Comment: so I've checked out your stack overflow for this exact thing, and I was wondering how to make it reset. I tried changing all constants to variable then setting them to zero with a reset function and it didn't work I used
```document.querySelectorAll("[reset]")
   .forEach(el => el.addEventListener("click", reset));
``` to try to find it and it didnt work, what could i do to fix this?

Comment: @ZainWilson-WCHStudent there's no need to reset anything from the above examples. Although - if you have external variables that count the number of games played and the number of wins - on click reset only those two. I cannot know what did not worked from one line of code. Post an example on a new question if you have an unrelated problem. - Also `"[reset]"` is not a valid selector. You mean rather: `".reset"` like for i.e: `<button class="reset" type="button">RESET</button>`?

Answer (score 0):

```js
function rock(playerInput) {
    
    this.playerInput = playerInput; 
    
}

var playerInput = 'blank'
var myRock = new rock(playerInput);
console.log(myRock.playerInput) // Should output "Blank"
```

If you want to make an object with function notation, you need to use the `new` keyword:

```js
var myRock = new rock();
```

And you should be passing the info to the object when you create it, not before. Try something like this.

```js
function rock(playerInput) {
    this.playerInput = playerInput; 
}

var myRock = new rock("Blank");
console.log(myRock.playerInput) // Should output "Blank"
```

Comment: The error i got was TypeError: rock is not a constructor"

Comment: Make sure you aren't using `rock` as your object as well as your function. They need to be different names. Make rock() the function, and then make a new var called myRock or something else.

Comment: Now i got undefined

Comment: And did you use the `new` keyword?

Comment: I have an answer to this question, it definitely made it a lot easier but thank you for your help