# Rock, paper, scissors: empty playerOne and playerTwo variables after function calls using an EventListener(click)?

Tags: javascript, html

**Goal**

My goal is to complete a game of rock, paper, scissors. I need to compare the input of two players that are behind the same computer, a simple game. The two players give their input through the buttons on an HTML page (rock, paper or scissor) that have an EventListener on them thanks to a JavaScript file I made.

**Problem**

Update: after feedback from others, I declared let variables outside the function. This gives me a new problem: I end up with two empty variables. Does anyone know how I solve this issue?

[image]

```
 const options = document.querySelectorAll(".options");
        var timesClicked = 0;

        console.log(options);

        let playerOneInput = "";
        let playerTwoInput = "";

        options.forEach((option) => {
            option.addEventListener("click", function () {
                timesClicked++;
                console.log(timesClicked);

                if (timesClicked == 1) {
                    let playerOneInput = this.textContent;
                    document.getElementById("player").innerHTML = "Player 2, choose your option!"
                } else {
                    let playerTwoInput = this.textContent; 
                };
                
                console.log(playerOneInput);
                console.log(playerTwoInput);

                if (timesClicked == 2) {
                    compareInputs(playerOneInput, playerTwoInput);
                }

            });
            
        });
```

```html
<h1 id='player'>Player 1, choose your option!</h1>
<button class="options">Rock</button>
<button class="options">Paper</button>
<button class="options">Scissors</button>
<h1>
  <div id='result'><div>
</h1>
```

I excluded the rest of my JS code which is the compareInputs function and result printing. Please let me know if you would like to see it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Read about variable scoping in JavaScript. You need to declare your variables outside of the event listener for them to persist.

Comment: Thank you. I tried doing that, but I ended up with empty let variables. Somehow, the values didn't get assigned.

Comment: I'm trying to understand... What has `timesClicked` anything to do with a RPS game?

Comment: PS: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53983473/383904) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65222824/383904) you have the probably simplest and cleanest code samples **and detailed explanation** on how to tackle Rock-Paper-Scissors logic

Comment: It's my way to connect the first player to the first click and the second player to the second click. They have to click on one of three buttons: rock, paper or scissor.

Comment: Much appreciated Roko! I saw the examples above, but unfortunately I'm not allowed to use a randomized computer entry as one of the players in the course that I am doing.

Comment: Ah soo, @HermanVulkers But you're only comparing 1 and 2... why? You should let it be `0`, if you remember **index** is `0` based! You need only to `timesClicked += 1;` **after** your logic, but also you need a `timesClicked %= 2;` to reset it back to `0`. Than to get which player turn is you can simply use Modulo operator again `% 2`

Answer (score 0):

As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53983473/383904) you'd better go with a game of indexes.

- Use a variable to count the number of turns `let turns`
- Use `turns % 2` to detect which player played
- Use buttons with `value="N"` where `N` are also indexes 0, 1, 2
- The [winner logic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53983473/383904):  `result = PL1 === PL2 ? 2 : (PL2 + 1) % 3 === PL1 ? 0 : 1;`
- Show the new title only once you increment the turn `turns += 1` and that piece of logic should go last!

```js
const ELS_options = document.querySelectorAll(".options");
const EL_title    = document.querySelector("#title");
const EL_result   = document.querySelector("#result");

let turns = 0; // 0 to N
const cards = ["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"]; // Values: 0,1,2
const names = ["One", "Two"];
const resultTexts = [
  `Player ${names[0]} won!`,
  `Player ${names[1]} won!`,
  `It's a draw!`
 ];
const moves = [[], []]; // 0 is for PL1, 1 is for PL2

const showResult = () => {
  const player = turns % 2; // 0,1,0,1,...
  if (player === 0) return EL_result.textContent = "";
  // Else....
  const round = Math.floor(turns / 2);
  // Collect both player moves
  const PL1 = moves[0][round];
  const PL2 = moves[1][round];
  // Get the result: //stackoverflow.com/a/53983473/383904
  const result = PL1 === PL2 ? 2 : (PL2 + 1) % 3 === PL1 ? 0 : 1;
  EL_result.innerHTML = `
    <div>Player ${names[0]} played: ${cards[PL1]}</div>
    <div>Player ${names[1]} played: ${cards[PL2]}</div>
    <h1>${resultTexts[result]}</h1>
  `;
};

const showTitle = () => {
  const player = turns % 2; // 0,1,0,1,...
  EL_title.textContent = `Player ${names[player]}, choose your move!`;
};

const onSelect = (evt) => {
  const player = turns % 2; // 0,1,0,1,...
  const move = parseInt(evt.currentTarget.value, 10); // 0,1,2
  moves[player].push(move); // Store the move
  showResult();
  turns += 1; // Advance turn
  showTitle(); 
};

// INIT APP:
ELS_options.forEach(EL => EL.addEventListener("click", onSelect));
showTitle();
```

```html
<h2 id='title'></h2>
<button value="0" class="options" type="button">Rock</button>
<button value="1" class="options" type="button">Paper</button>
<button value="2" class="options" type="button">Scissors</button>
<div id='result'></div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your effort to help and find a solution. Much appreciated!

Comment: You're welcome Herman

Answer (score -1):

The variable is undefined because you create it inside a function. Try declaring the variable outside the function and changing this global variable inside the function

```
let inputPlayer1 = "";

function onInput() {
  inputPlayer1 = "rock"; // the selected type
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I tried your suggestion, but it gives me back empty variables. No values are added to the declared variables somehow.

Comment: @HermanVulkers as stated in the answer, do not create a new variable in the function scope instead modify the global variable. You can achieve this by removing `let` in front of the decleration (in the function scope)