# How to separated onclick event in the list of buttons Javascript DOM

Tags: javascript, dom, onclicklistener

I'm a novice to `Javscript DOM` and try making a `Rock Paper Scissors Game`. In that game, I want to customize the `onclick` event that I'm the person who can decide and click on both options among `paper, scissors, or rock`.

In `game.html` I have 3 options as 3 button events for each `paper, rock, and scissors`

```
<div class="decisions">
            <input
                class="options"
                type="image"
                disabled="true"
                src="./assets/rock.svg"
                value="Rock"
            />
            <input
                class="options"
                disabled="true"
                type="image"
                src="./assets/paper.svg"
                value="Paper"
            />
            <input
                class="options"
                type="image"
                disabled="true"
                src="./assets/scissors.svg"
                value="Scissors"
            />
</div>
```

`main.js`

```
const options = document.querySelectorAll(".options")

const startGame = () => {
    // list of options 
    const _options = ["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"]
    options.forEach(option => {
        option.addEventListener("click", function () {
             // this is my turn 
            let hInput = this.value
            // this is random turn for computer, but I want to to make this turn
            // by myself
            let cInput = _options[Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)]
            if (hInput && cInput) {
                updateScore(hInput, cInput)
                compareInputs(hInput, cInput)
            }
        })
    })
}
```

How do I separate the `addEventListender` to make 2 different turns by myself?

Comment: can you please explain more what do you mean by : 
" to make 2 different turns by myself?"

Comment: @John I want to be the person who can decide both turns. not one for human and random one for computer.

Comment: how can human decide? because this code is looping on all the buttons , and all buttons are taking random value to send to the functions.
should there any other button for human?

Comment: @John, `let p1Input = this.value` is for human turn, and the `let p2Input = _options[Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)]` is random turn for computer after human clicks.

Comment: @john I just be able to implement one turn for human and the other is random for computer, so I want to know whether is there any other approach that human can make 2 turns.

Comment: iam not sure yet about the exact thing you want to do but if you want to remove the random turn , and make it by human , you should just change `_options[Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)]` to `_options[this.value]` 
dont know you knew this before or not :D . correct me if iam wrong

Comment: *"human can make two turns"*? You mean, instead of using a computer as opponent you want to make a Two Players turn-game?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan yeah, that is what I mean.

Comment: @John, I've tried the way you said, but it didn't work.

Comment: Well, that remove the `random` part and keep track of which player is playing using an index.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Thank you for the kind reply. But do I need to make one more `addEventListener` event? or just use one only?

Comment: Using one listener would suffice if you were to implement a _state machine_ for the game. Basically, the program itself decides how to handle the button click, depending on which player's turn it is.

Comment: You need to attach a click event only once in JS. Than inside the function that handles it increment a numeric variable `player ` by 1: `player  += 1;`. To get the odd/even simply do `console.log(player % 2)`

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan "You need to" sounds like you think it's the only solution to this problem. In programming (and most aspects of life), there are almost always _multiple_ solutions to a problem. K_ng's idea of multiple listeners is definitely a possibility, though I would not recommend it for reasons.

Comment: Please take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53983473/383904 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/69665745/383904 for more ideas on how to tackle with a RPS logic.

Answer (score 1):

## State machines

I recommend to implement some kind of [*state machine*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine). *(Finite) state machines* have states, and moving to another state is called a *transition*. Such a transition may move to different states depending on the input provided.

### In your case...

Simply put, we can use a state machine that depending on whose turn it is, it remembers the input as the selection of either player 1 (P1) or player 2 (P2). Only if both have made their selection you want to evaluate who has won, which would be after P2 has made theirs.

Your state machine may look like this:

1. Await P1's input.
2. Await P2's input.

With the transitions defined as:

1. On state 1:

   1. Remember input as P1's value.
   2. Go to state 2.
2. On state 2:

   1. Remember input as P2's value.
   2. Evaluate winner.
   3. Go to state 1.

Each transition would be triggered by a button click, and the input would be the value of the button. Obviously you can add outputs during the transitions for the *user-experience* (UX; it's an interesting topic in (web) design!).

*How* the state machine is implemented (or even defined!) is up to you. Adding and removing listeners depending on the state would also be a viable solution, though that may not be as performant.

### Example solution

Here is an example of how such a state machine could be implemented. Also, I added comments to the steps that I described above for the transitions.
(**Sidenote:** "State 1" is at index 0, "State 2" at 1, etc. because of zero-indexing in JS—and most other programming languages, so don't be confused by it!)

```js
class StateMachine {
  #data = {};
  #transitionHandlers;
  #currentState = 0;

  constructor(...transitionHandlers) {
    this.#transitionHandlers = transitionHandlers;
  }
  
  next(...args) {
    const transitionHandler = this.#transitionHandlers[this.#currentState];
    this.#currentState = transitionHandler(this.#currentState, this.#data, ...args);
  }
}

const options = document.querySelectorAll("button");
const output = document.querySelector("output");

const newGame = () => {
  output.append("\nPlayer 1, choose!");
  output.textContent = output.textContent.trim(); // Trims "\n" if no end-result was shown previously
};
const transition0Handler = (i, data, value) => {
  data.player1 = Number(value); // 1.1
  output.replaceChildren("Player 2, choose!");
  return 1; // 1.2
};
const transition1Handler = (i, data, value) => {
  data.player2 = Number(value); // 2.1
  
  // 2.2
  const result = ((data.player1 + 3) - data.player2) % 3;
  if (result === 0) {
    output.replaceChildren("It's a draw!");
  } else {
    output.replaceChildren(`Player ${result} won!`);
  }
  
  newGame();
  return 0; // 2.3
};

const game = new StateMachine(transition0Handler, transition1Handler);

document.querySelector("body").addEventListener("click", evt => {
  const button = evt.target.closest("button");
  if (button) {
    game.next(button.dataset.value); // Evaluate the game's next transition with our input
  }
});

newGame();
```

```css
output {display:block;white-space:pre}
```

```html
<button data-value="0">Rock</button>
<button data-value="1">Paper</button>
<button data-value="2">Scissor</button>
<output></output>
```

#### Math-y winner evaluation

We can arrange "Rock", "Paper", "Scissor" so that:

- P1 wins if they choose the next following option of P2's selection.
- P2 wins if they choose the next following option of P1's selection.
- Otherwise—both choose the same—they draw.

Since we only have 3 selections, calculating these outcomes is simple:
We can interpret the difference of the selections as an integer of the [*residue system*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic#Residue_systems) of modulo 3 (a [*ring*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_(mathematics))). To make it work in JS, we need to keep the integer positive before calculating the modulo. We do this by adding 3 (the size of our result-set) to the [minuend](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subtraction#Notation_and_terminology) (the number we reduce).

Now the result we get is one of [0,1,2], where 0 means that both chose the same, and the other possibilities mean that either of the players has won. If we reduced P1's value, then "1" would stand for P1's win, and vice versa.

This can be output as in the code above:

```js
if (result === 0) {
  output.replaceChildren("It's a draw!");
} else {
  output.replaceChildren(`Player ${result} won!`);
}
```

Obviously, a few *if*-statements would have done the trick as well.