# Rock Paper Scissors declare winner logic

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to code a simple Rock Paper Scissors game with three images that the player clicks on to trigger an event listener and initiate the start of the game `playGame()`.
Where I'm running into problems with my second function, `declareWinner()` which should evaluate the if/else statements and user and computer selection and declare the winner. I think the issue is with the `userInput` but I don't know what the problem is. Each time the game runs it skips to the `else` statement and console.logs *"It's a tie."*.
What am I doing wrong?

Here is my HTML and CSS

```
//Initialize scores to zero
let yourScore = 0;
let computerScore = 0;
let roundNum = 0;
let userInput;
let computerInput;

//Global Variables
const userRock = document.querySelector(".user-rock");
const userPaper = document.querySelector(".user-paper");
const userScissors = document.querySelector(".user-scissors");
const computerRock = document.querySelector(".computer-rock");
const computerPaper = document.querySelector(".computer-paper");
const computerScissors = document.querySelector(".computer-scissors");
const scoreUser = document.querySelector(".user-score");
const scoreComputer = document.querySelector(".computer-score");


let computerSelection = document.getElementById("computer-selection");
          
// Adding event listener to User icons
userRock.addEventListener("click", playGame);
userPaper.addEventListener("click", playGame);
userScissors.addEventListener("click", playGame);

// Create playGame() to start game when image is clicked
function playGame (){
    let computerInput = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
        if (computerInput === 1) {
            computerInput === 'rock'
            console.log ("computer chose rock");
        }
        if (computerInput === 2) {
            computerInput === 'paper'        
            console.log ("computer chose paper");
        }
        if (computerInput === 3) {
            computerInput === 'scissors'
            console.log ("computer chose scissors");
        }
    evaluateRound(userInput, computerInput);
}

    function evaluateRound(userInput, computerInput) {
        if(userInput === 'rock' && computerInput === 'paper') {
            console.log ('You lose! Paper beats rock!'); 
            scoreComputer.innerHTML = scoreComputer++;    
        } if (userInput === 'rock' && computerInput === 'rock') {
            console.log ('Its a tie!');     
        } if (userInput === 'rock' && computerInput === 'scissors') {
            console.log ('You win! Rock beats scissors!');
            scoreUser.innerHTML = scoreUser++;      
        // User Chooses Paper
        } else if(userInput === "paper" && computerInput === 'rock') {
            console.log ('You win! Rock beats paper!');   
            scoreUser.innerHTML = scoreUser++;     
        } else if (userInput === 'paper' && computerInput === 'paper') {
            console.log ('Its a tie!');     
        } else if (userInput === 'paper' && computerInput === 'scissors') {
            console.log ('You lose! Scissors beats paper!'); 
            scoreComputer.innerHTML = scoreComputer++;    
        // User Chooses Scissors
        } else if(userInput === "scissors" && computerInput === 'rock') {
            console.log ('You lose! Rock beats scissors!');     
            scoreComputer.innerHTML = scoreComputer++; 
        } else if (userInput === 'scissors' && computerInput === 'paper') {
            console.log ('You win! Scissors beats paper!'); 
            scoreUser.innerHTML = scoreUser++;      
        } else {
            console.log ('It"s a tie!');  
        }  
    }
```

and

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css"> 
    <title>Rock Paper Scissors</title>
    <h1> Rock Paper Scissors</h1>
    <h2> The first player to get <span>5 points</span> wins!</h2>

    <p>SCORE:</p> 
   
    <div class="score-board">
        <div class="computer-score">0</div>  
        <div class="user-score">0</div>  
    </div>

    <div class="gameboard">    
        <div class="user-choices">
            <div class="user-instructions">You chose:<div class="user-selection"></div>
            <div class="user-icons">
                <div class="game-button">
                    <img class ="user-rock" src="rock.jpg" height="60px"></img>
                    <h3>Rock</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="game-button">
                    <img class="user-paper" src="paper.jpg" height="60px"></img>
                    <h3>Paper</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="game-button">
                    <img class="user-scissors" src="scissors.jpg" height="60px"></img>
                    <h3>Scissors</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    
        <div class="computer-choices">
            <div class="computer-instructions">Computer chose:<div class="computer-selection"></div>
            <div class="computer-icons">
                <div class="rock-selection">
                    <img class="computer-rock" src="rock.jpg" height="60px"></img>
                    <h3>Rock</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="paper-selection">
                    <img class="computer-paper" src="paper.jpg" height="60px"></img>
                    <h3>Paper</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="scissors-selection">
                    <img class="computer-scissors" src="scissors.jpg" height="60px"></img>
                    <h3>Scissors</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
  

</head>
<body>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You forgot to pass the `userInput` & `computerInput` variables to `evaluateRound` function. So in `evaluateRound` those variables never equal to any of the `rock`, `paper`, `scissors` strings, hence the execution of the code in `else`. Oh, and you also never define what the `userInput` is.

Comment: Hi Ivanka, thanks for looking over my code and helping out! So I made the following changes: ``` let userInput = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"]; ``` and I passed in the two arguments (userInput, computerInput) as follows ``` evaluateRound(userInput, computerInput)``` but it is still console.logging "It's a tie" in other words skipping to else condition

Comment: Would you update your code in your question with the changes you described, it's a little bit unreadable as a comment.

Comment: See: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65222824/383904), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53983473/383904)  - in short, using `if` statements is clunky and repetitive, you can use a much simpler logic to determine win, lost, draw, the needed messages, etc - by just using integers **indexes**.

Comment: Hey Roko, thanks for the feedback I really appreciate it! I just started learning on The Odin Project's website and this RPS game is only their second project so I would like to stick with using if/else statements instead of indexes which I haven't learned yet. Do you see a solution using what I've currently written? I think the problem is y userInput but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. I plan on spending the next week making different versions of RPS game using simpler logic like using integer indexes you suggested, but for now I don't want to complicate things too much :) Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

- Your indexes logic is wrong   `Math.floor(Math.random() * 4)` can give you `0,1,2,3` — but you only need `0,1,2`.
- The document tags that are part of your app should go in `<body>`, not in `<head>`

Also given Rock Paper Scissors *is* actually a game of indexes, you could convert your logic to something more simpler:

```js
const fig = ["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"];
const msg = ["You won", "You lost", "It's a draw"];
const score = [0, 0, 0]; // 0= PL's score,  1= AI's score, 2=Total Draws

function play() {
  const PL = Number(this.dataset.player);   // Get 0, 1, 2 from button data-player
  const AI = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3); // Generate random 0, 1, 2 integer

  let res; // Result to be determined:

  if (PL === AI) {
    res = 2;  // Draw
  } else if ((AI + 1) % 3 === PL) {
    res = 0;  // Player wins
  } else {
    res = 1;  // Computer wins
  }
  
  score[res] += 1;

  console.log(`
    ${msg[res]} 
    You played: ${fig[PL]}
    Computer played: ${fig[AI]} 
    Score: Player: ${score[0]} Computer: ${score[1]} Draws: ${score[2]}
  `);
}

document.querySelectorAll("[data-player]").forEach((el) => {
  el.addEventListener("click", play);
});
```

```html
<button data-player="0" type="button">ROCK</button>
<button data-player="1" type="button">PAPER</button>
<button data-player="2" type="button">SCISSORS</button>
```

Let's examine the key concept of ***"RPS is a game if indexes"***.

The easiest logic is when PL equals AI. So having that one eliminated,
Player wins if: we add `1` to AI's result and after a Modulo `%3` the values are equal. The last one possibility is: Computer has won.

Why the modulo logic works is because of the order R-P-S or `0 1 2`, which is a linear **wins-over** sequence.

```
// Rock Paper Scissors - win logic:

 ...  0R  1P  2S  ...  wins over:
     /   /   /   /    
    /   /   /   /
 ...  0R  1P  2S  ...
```

by using `% 3` (in the `(AI + 1) % 3`) we're just making sure to cover the above's `...` cases.

Without the `if, else` the above can be also rewritten using the (Conditional) **[Ternary Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)** `statement ? ifTrue : ifFalse` :

```js
const fig = ["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"];
const msg = ["You won", "You lost", "It's a draw"];
const score = [0, 0, 0];

function play() {
  const PL = Number(this.dataset.player);   // Get 0, 1, 2 from button data-player
  const AI = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3); // Generate random 0, 1, 2 integer
  let res = PL === AI ? 2 : (AI + 1) % 3 === PL ? 0 : 1; // Determine result
  score[res] += 1;
  console.log(`
    ${msg[res]}!
    You played: ${fig[PL]},
    Computer played: ${fig[AI]}
    Score: Player: ${score[0]} Computer: ${score[1]} Draws: ${score[2]}
  `);
}

document.querySelectorAll("[data-player]").forEach(el => el.addEventListener("click", play));
```

```html
<button data-player="0" type="button">ROCK</button>
<button data-player="1" type="button">PAPER</button>
<button data-player="2" type="button">SCISSORS</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I defined userInput and kept my if/else statements and now it works. Will work on refactoring my code and trying different simpler types of logic next. thanks for everyone who looked at my code!

```
function getComputerChoice() {
    const choices = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors'];
    const ranNum = choices[Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)];
    return ranNum;
}

function playRound(userInput) {
    const computerInput = getComputerChoice();

if(userInput === 'rock' && computerInput === 'paper') {
        computerScore++; 
        computerScore_div.innerHTML = computerScore;
        userSelection_div.innerHTML = "You chose " + userInput;
        computerSelection_div.innerHTML = "Computer chose " + computerInput;
    } if (userInput === 'rock' && computerInput === 'rock') {
        userSelection_div.innerHTML = "You chose " + userInput;
        computerSelection_div.innerHTML = "Computer chose " + computerInput; 
    } if (userInput === 'rock' && computerInput === 'scissors') {
        userScore++;    
        userScore_div.innerHTML = userScore;
        userSelection_div.innerHTML = "You chose " + userInput;
        computerSelection_div.innerHTML = "Computer chose " + computerInput;
    // User Chooses Paper
    } else if(userInput === "paper" && computerInput === 'rock') {
        userScore++;     
        userScore_div.innerHTML = userScore;
        userSelection_div.innerHTML = "You chose " + userInput;
        computerSelection_div.innerHTML = "Computer chose " + computerInput;
    } else if (userInput === 'paper' && computerInput === 'paper') {
        console.log ('You chose paper and computer chose paper. It"s a tie!');     
    } else if (userInput === 'paper' && computerInput === 'scissors') {
        computerScore++;   
        computerScore_div.innerHTML = computerScore;
        userSelection_div.innerHTML = "You chose " + userInput;
        computerSelection_div.innerHTML = "Computer chose " + computerInput;
    // User Chooses Scissors
    } else if(userInput === "scissors" && computerInput === 'rock') {
        computerScore++;
        computerScore_div.innerHTML = computerScore;
        userSelection_div.innerHTML = "You chose " + userInput;
        computerSelection_div.innerHTML = "Computer chose " + computerInput;
    } else if (userInput === 'scissors' && computerInput === 'paper') {
        userScore++;     
        userScore_div.innerHTML = userScore;
        userSelection_div.innerHTML = "You chose " + userInput;
        computerSelection_div.innerHTML = "Computer chose " + computerInput;
    } else {
        userSelection_div.innerHTML = "You chose " + userInput;
        computerSelection_div.innerHTML = "Computer chose " + computerInput;
    }  

}

function playGame() {
    userRock.addEventListener("click", function () {
        playRound("rock");
    })
    userPaper.addEventListener("click", function () {
        playRound("paper");
    })
    userScissors.addEventListener("click", function () {
        playRound("scissors");
    })
}

playGame();
```