# Need to display result after end of round 5 without clicking event. Rock Paper Scissor game

Tags: javascript, function, callback

I am trying to Build Rock paper scissor game in this everything is working fine. But the issue is after the end of 5 rounds the endGame function is not executing immediately it is showing result after i click on buttons again. The result should display after the end of 5 round without me clicking the button again.

```
const choices = ["Rock","Paper","Scissor"];
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll("button");
let playerid = document.getElementById("playerid"); 
let computerid = document.getElementById("computerid");
const playermarks = document.getElementById("playerscore");
const computermarks = document.getElementById("computerscore");
const res = document.getElementById("res");
let computer;
let computerSelection;
let playerSelection;
//computer choice
function computerChoice(){
    computerSelection = choices[Math.floor(Math.random()*choices.length)];
    computerid.innerHTML = computerSelection;
    console.log("computerSelection",computerSelection);
}

buttons.forEach((btn) => {
    btn.addEventListener("click",(playerChoice));
})
//player choice
function playerChoice(e){
   playerSelection= e.target.innerHTML;
            playerid.innerHTML =playerSelection;
            console.log(" playerSelection", playerSelection);
            computerChoice();
            playGame();
            
}


//Round
function playRound(computerSel,playerSel){

    return (playerSel == computerSel) ? "Its a Tie" :
    ((computerSel == "Rock" && playerSel == "Paper") ||
    (computerSel == "Paper" && playerSel == "Rock") ||
    (computerSel == "Scissor" && playerSel == "Rock")) ? "computer won" : "player won";
}

// 5 Round



let playerScore = 0;
let computerScore = 0;
let round=0
function playGame(){
    
   
    if(round < 5){
        let result = playRound(computerSelection,playerSelection);
        console.log("result",result);
        if(result == "computer won"){
            computerScore++;
            computermarks.innerHTML = computerScore;
            console.log("computer Score",computerScore);
        }else if(result == "player won"){
             playerScore++;
             playermarks.innerHTML = playerScore;
            console.log("playerscore",playerScore);
        }
        round++;
    }else{
        endGame(computerScore,playerScore);
    }
    
    }
    
function endGame(cs,ps){
    if(cs > ps){
        res.innerHTML = "The Winner is Computer";
        console.log("The Winner is Computer");
    }else if (cs < ps){
        console.log("The Winner is Computer");
        res.innerHTML = "The Winner is Computer";
    }else{
        console.log("Its a tie")
        res.innerHTML = "Its a tie";
    }
}
```

I have also tried with else if(round == 5) and else if( round == 5) or with 4 but still it is showing result after i click on button. With for loop i was facing lot of issues hence tried with if else.

Comment: Please (since you still have not) take a [tour] to learn how this site works. Welcome to Stack Overflow

Comment: Not an answer to your specific question but I believe you might find this related one really interesting [Rock Paper Scissors winner logic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70815049/383904)

Answer (score 1):

In `playGame`, move the `endGame` call inside the `if` block, and make it conditional to `round` being 5 after you've increased it. The `else` block means the game *was* already over, and nothing should happen.

```
    if(round < 5){
        let result = playRound(computerSelection,playerSelection);
        console.log("result",result);
        if(result == "computer won"){
            computerScore++;
            computermarks.innerHTML = computerScore;
            console.log("computer Score",computerScore);
        }else if(result == "player won"){
             playerScore++;
             playermarks.innerHTML = playerScore;
            console.log("playerscore",playerScore);
        }
        round++;
        // Check whether this was the last round:
        if (round === 5) {
            endGame(computerScore,playerScore);
        }
    } // No else-case
```

Still, after this correction, the buttons can still be clicked, and you'd get into a continuation of the game that was already finished. One way to deal with that is to consider the next button click the first round of a *new* game. So at that button click the game should be "reset". You could for instance start the `playGame` function with this code:

```
    if (round === 5) { // Game was already over. Start a new game:
        playerScore = 0;
        computerScore = 0;
        round = 0;        
        playermarks.innerHTML = "";
        computermarks.innerHTML = "";
        res.innerHTML = "";
    }
```

... and then have it followed by the code you already had (with the suggested correction).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions i have utilized it.. Now code is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this issue, you need to check if the round count is equal to 5 immediately after the playerChoice() function is called, and then call the endGame() function if the condition is met.

```
function playerChoice(e){
        playerSelection= e.target.innerHTML;
        playerid.innerHTML =playerSelection;
        console.log(" playerSelection", playerSelection);
        computerChoice();
        playGame();
        
        if (round === 5) {
           endGame(computerScore, playerScore);
        }
}
```

With this change, the endGame() function will be called immediately after the 5th round is completed, without requiring an additional button click.